# Drupal 7 custom block

Tags: php, css, drupal-7

I would like to position a block to a certain position to the website. In this case can be the website logo or a language switcher. ( I know there is a tag for the logo but I want to create something a little more complex )

My idea is something like create a custom component ( put php if needed ) and style it with my custom css.

My question is: How can I link my recently created block with a css?

Thanks

Comment: Just informational: There is also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ now for Drupal-specific topics. This question is of course programming-related and might still get answered on SO. Only if it shouldn't, you could flag it for moderator attention to have to moved to DrupalAnswers.SE

Comment: Ok, I didn't know... My fault ( +1 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating regions was what I needed.